# How can I save values in a safe way. ie for Favorites

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, favorites

I have an application that I would like my users to save these values:

- LDAP Connection String
- Username
- Password

The thing is this application is Windows Forms and has to be able to run on Windows XP/Vista/7 but also on Server 2003 and Server 2008.

With that in mind, how would you suggest I save these settings three values. Remember each favorite (which can be N amount) has one of each of these properties.

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with Encryption. Just saving plain old string for consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Use the user.config file that .NET 2.0+ provides support for. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/appsettings2005.aspx) might be useful.

Of course, saving passwords in cleartext is never recommended.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this .Net has an isolated storage. It is possible to select what will be the scope of the isolated storage machine/application/user etc. Depneding on scope the .Net creates a special directory under user or machine profile, where the application can store special application/user related data.
To get the storage the following commad is used:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(
    IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User, null, null);
```

To get files in the specific Isolated storage the GetFileNames is used:

```
string[] fileNames = isoStore.GetFileNames();
```

To create or open a stream in the isolated storage:

```
// use the correct FileMode flag Open/Create/Trancate/etc.
IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
    <file_name>, FileMode.Create, isoStore);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to save a list of that three values in an encrypted way, I can suggest to save the list in a zip file protected by a very strong password using [Ionic.Zip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).
You can read zip as stream, without the need to decompress it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ProtectedData  in System.Security.Cryptography to safely save these stuff so that only user can decrypt it. Windows uses it internally to save your login details.

[MSDN Article on ProtectedData](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/05/05/126825.aspx)